# recombine list after blocking parts of it in the same order

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
lst1 = [1,8,3,2,5,7,9,10,11]
```

I have a function that produces output

```
lst2 = [[1,8],[2,5],[10,11]]
```

I want to recombine the list - keeping everything in the same order numerically as the first list

```
desired_output = [[1,8],[3],[2,5],[7],[9],[10,11]]
```

My code is almost unreadable so im not including it.  It also throws errors.

Comment: You should include your code anyway, it helps to understand the problem. Also, the errors may say a lot about what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Another question, what would happen if the `lst2` had a inner list with a pair of values that is not in sequence? for instance `[2,7]`

Comment: [luigibertaco] it would be an error and not useful for me.  Everything needs to stay in order of the first list

Comment: Is it not possible to modify the function? Seems like that would be easier.

Comment: wjandrea thats a good idea and I have tried it, but I have been messing with it for a few hours and got burnt out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each group in `lst2`, see if it matches the start of `lst1`. If so, add it to the out list and remove the start of `lst1`. Otherwise pop the first item of `lst1` into the out list and try again.

```
out = []
for group in lst2:
    n = len(group)
    while True:
        if lst1[:n] == group:
            out.append(group)
            del lst1[:n]
            break
        else:
            out.append([lst1.pop(0)])

print(out)  # -> [[1, 8], [3], [2, 5], [7], [9], [10, 11]]
```

P.s. Since you mentioned in the comments that `lst2` must be in a specific format, but didn't say what that format is, I haven't bothered to think about all possible inputs.

Comment: This is great!  Thank You!